# How to validate form using Yup and Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I need to validate checkboxes if they are in the DOM.

This is my validation schema. So depending whether some state is true or false I am showing either confirm1 or confirm2 checkbox. Currently fields are not showing errors and I can not submit the form.

```
 const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    confirm1: yup.boolean().notRequired()
    .when('confirm2', {
      is: (val) => val === true,
      then: yup.boolean().required('Field must be checked'),
      otherwise: yup.boolean().notRequired()
    }),
    confirm2: yup.boolean().notRequired()
    .when('confirm1', {
      is: (val) => val === true,
      then: yup.boolean().required('Field must be checked'),
      otherwise: yup.boolean().notRequired()
    })
  }, ['confirm1', 'confirm2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found solution for this, i have just changed it like this and it worked as expected

```
confirm1: yup.boolean().notRequired()
  .when('confirm2', {
     is: (val) => val !== true,
     then: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'Field must be checked'),
     otherwise: yup.boolean().required()
  }),
confirm1: yup.boolean().notRequired()
    .when('confirm2', {
      is: (val) => val !== true,
      then: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'Field must be checked'),
      otherwise: yup.boolean().required()
    }),
```